# HTML - Spacing between rows in table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table that uses rowspan to combine 2 rows. I want the spacing between the 2 non combined rows to be closer whilst maintaining a larger spacing between the overall rows. For example, I would like `row1 col1` and `row2 col1` to be spaced closer together whilst having a larger space between `row2 col1` and `row3 col1`. This would apply to each overall row.

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.noborder {
 border:none;
}
```

```html
<table>
 <tr>
  <td class="noborder">row1 col1</td>
  <td rowspan=2>merge col2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>row2 col1</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="noborder">row3 col1</td>
  <td rowspan=2>merge col2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>row4 col1</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="noborder">row6 col1</td>
  <td rowspan=2>merge col2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>row6 col1</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: One solution could be that you can add one empty row after each table row like `<tr><td class="noborder">&nbsp;</td></tr>`.

Answer (score 0):

What this? But your td is not valid when you use one column and the next row two. Use the colspan (https://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/att_td_colspan.asp) attribute instead.

```
table {
        border-collapse:separate; 
        border-spacing:5px;
    }
```

Comment: How can I combine 2 rows by using colspan?

Comment: @Matt9Atkins Is possible to use rowspan same function as colspan but on rows